# Can I have a boost lock-free queue of lambdas?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to implement a messaging system that will work across multiple threads. `boost::lockfree::queue` seemed like a good direction to go in, unfortunately I'm having trouble creating a queue of either `std::function` or `boost::function` types as apparently they don't have trivial assignment and destructor's which is a requirement of `boost::lockfree::queue`.

My following code:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
//#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::lockfree::queue<boost::function<void(int)>> queue;
  assert(queue.is_lock_free());

  for(int j = 0; j < 50; ++j) {
    queue.push([] (int i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; });
  }

  int i = 0;
  boost::function<void(int)> functor;
  while (queue.pop(functor)) {
    functor(i++);
  }
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/integer.hpp:23:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/function_base.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/prologue.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:24,
                 from lockfree.cpp:5:
/usr/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp: In instantiation of ‘class boost::lockfree::queue<boost::function<void(int)> >’:
lockfree.cpp:10:54:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:81:5: error: static assertion failed (boost::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value)
     BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((boost::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value));
     ^
/usr/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:85:5: error: static assertion failed (boost::has_trivial_assign<T>::value)
     BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((boost::has_trivial_assign<T>::value));
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could still use *stateless* lambdas with raw function pointers, if that's an option:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>

int main() {
    //boost::lockfree::queue<boost::function<void(int)>> queue(50);
    boost::lockfree::queue<void (*)(int)> queue(50);
    assert(queue.is_lock_free());

    for (int j = 0; j < 50; ++j) {
        queue.push([](int i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; });
    }

    int i = 0;
    boost::function<void(int)> functor;
    while (queue.pop(functor)) {
        functor(i++);
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d57770e3be029760

Comment: Is this safe? Basically you are holding a pointer to a temporary function?

Comment: @Nim, to tell the truth, I'm not sure... since stateless lambdas are just raw functions, and I "think" they will live as long as the program, the same way a string literal lives... but I dunno whether there's a standard quotation backing this.

Comment: @Nim, by the way, that's an interesting question =)

Comment: Thanks! This is interesting. In production I'll be storing these functions as class members and referencing them because I don't want to do lots of heap allocation... So the fact that in your example they're temporary shouldn't conflict with the idea.

Comment: The lambda is a type rather than an instance, so it has no restricted lifetime.

Comment: @pepper_chico Thanks for the example, it's super useful. The last bit I'm trying to figure out is how to push a `boost::function<>` into the queue. I suppose I need to wrap it into a lambda:  `void pushJob(boost::function<void ()> job) { jobQueue.push([job] { job(); }); }` but that doesn't compile: No suitable conversion from "lambda []void()->void" to "void (*const)()" exists.

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune it only worked b/c it was stateless, which can be converted to bare function pointers. When there's state, like you're trying to do, this conversion isn't possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pointers to emulate trivial types. (This works for all lambdas)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::lockfree::queue<boost::function<void(int)>*> queue(3);
  assert(queue.is_lock_free());

  for(int j = 0; j < 50; ++j) {
    auto function = [] (int i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; };
    queue.push(new boost::function<void(int)>(function));
  }

  int i = 0;
  boost::function<void(int)> * functor;
  while (queue.pop(functor)) {
    functor->operator()(i++);
    delete functor;
  }
}
```

Comment: If `queue.push(new boost::function<void(int)>(function));` fails, there is one new function that leaks memory. In the examples push is wrapped into an while loop like `while (!queue.push(value));`. This can be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

boost::function does not satisfies requirements for lock free queue:

> - trivial copy constructor
> - trivial assignment
> - trivial destructor

Here's a [thread](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2013/04/202104.php) on the mailing list describing the same problem you have, the solution would likely be to use a functor object which can be copied.