# Wrap boost::function into lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm trying to make this code compile:

```
typedef void (*func_ptr)();

boost::function<void()> bf;
func_ptr fp = [bf] { bf(); };
```

Visual Studio 2015 complains that no suitable conversion from `lambda []void()->void` to `void (*const)()` exists.

What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot convert a capturing lambda into a regular function pointer... there's data involved.

Comment: Ah, good point. I need to backtrack a bit then: What I'm trying to do is have a `boost::lockfree::queue<>` of functions but since `boost::function<void()>` is neither trivially assignable nor destructable, I'm trying with a  `boost::lockfree::queue<void (*)()>`, in the spirit of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405837/can-i-have-a-boost-lock-free-queue-of-lambdas.