# boost::lockfree::queue of functions?

Tags: c++, boost

I'd like to build a simple `boost::lockfree::queue` of functions that take no arguments and return no values.

It appears that `boost::lockfree::queue` requires the item type to be trivially assignable and destructible, requirements that `boost::function<void ()>` unfortunately doesn' meet.

In the spirit of https://stackoverflow.com/a/21406186/393756, I'm now trying to achieve this by a `boost::lockfree::queue` of plain function pointers:

```
boost::lockfree::queue<void (*)()> queue;
```

**Can I push a `boost::function<void ()>` into this queue?** If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I push a `boost::function<void()>` into this queue?

Not directly, as `boost::function<void()>` is an heavyweight owning type-erased wrapper that is not implicitly convertible to a *function pointer* and also stores some data.

If you need a trivially-assignable an trivially-destructible type that can **refer** to any function object, you could implement a `function_view` class that points to some function object without owning it. If you're careful with lifetimes and guarantee that `function_view` always points to "live objects" you can safely store instances of that in your queue.

Conceptually, `function_view` is a pair of pointers. I have an implementation in my [**"passing functions to functions"**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html) article, which I'm pasting below:

```
template <typename TReturn, typename... TArgs>
class function_view<TReturn(TArgs...)> final
{
private:
    using signature_type = TReturn(void*, TArgs...);

    void* _ptr;
    TReturn (*_erased_fn)(void*, TArgs...);

public:
    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<
                              std::is_callable<T&(TArgs...)>{} &&
                              !std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, function_view>{}>>
    function_view(T&& x) noexcept : _ptr{(void*)std::addressof(x)}
    {
        _erased_fn = [](void* ptr, TArgs... xs) -> TReturn {
            return (*reinterpret_cast<std::add_pointer_t<T>>(ptr))(
                std::forward<TArgs>(xs)...);
        };
    }

    decltype(auto) operator()(TArgs... xs) const
        noexcept(noexcept(_erased_fn(_ptr, std::forward<TArgs>(xs)...)))
    {
        return _erased_fn(_ptr, std::forward<TArgs>(xs)...);
    }
};
```

This class passes the following tests:

```
using type = function_view<void()>;
static_assert(is_trivially_assignable<type, type>{});
static_assert(is_trivially_destructible<type>{});
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DPR8Jw7ptMoeeVLp)

Comment: but then you have to worry about the view not viewing a valid object. meaning you need to manage the lifetime of the function. it is quit hard when you talk about threading. how would you know that the view has done doing its work and you can delete the function?

Comment: @DavidHaim: it depends on the use case of the OP. If the ownership/lifetime hierarchy is unclear, a `shared_ptr`/`unique_ptr` is a better fit. But he if has some sort of "parent scope" where all functions live or some sort of "manager" where he can store functions, a view might be a better fit / more efficient.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo To answer your question: in my scenario, there's no manager that owns the functions.

Answer (score 1):

no, but you can use dynamic memory allocation + type erasure for that cause:

```
struct callback_back{

   virtual void execute() = 0;
   ~callback_base() = default;

};

template<class F>
class callback{

  private:
     F m_function;

  public:
    callback(F&& function) : m_function(std::forward<F>(function)){}

    virtual void execute() {
        m_function();
    }

}

template<class F>
std::unique_ptr<callback_base> make_callback(F&& f){
    return std::unique_ptr<callback_base>(
       new callback<F>(std::forward<F>(f));
    );
}
```

use `callback_base` as a noexcept-movable type (aka `boost::lockfree::queue<std::unique_ptr<callback_base>>`).

Comment: Note that `unique_ptr` cannot be stored in a `lockfree::queue` as it's not trivially destructible: https://wandbox.org/permlink/1E6MFC2KVB7xtbN7

Comment: ha. interesting. well in this case one can use `boost::lockfree::queue<callback_base*>` and wrap the queue in some very thin wrapper which gets and returns a `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found so far is to make a raw pointer of the function object

```
boost::lockfree::queue<std::function<void(void)> *> tasks_; // the queue
// let f = stack allocated std::function<T(T)> instance
tasks_.push(new std::function<void(void)>(f));
// pop
std::function<void(void)> * f;
tasks_.pop(f);
// execute in try/catch make sure to delete in case of exception?
(*f)();
// you should delete f here if you are done with it

// in the destructor of the class that owns tasks_ you should delete the remaining std::function instances
```

The challenge here is to when to delete this instance with exception safety in mind